# Python, Catch timeout during stream request

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

I'm reading XML events with the requests library as stated in the code below. How do I raise a connection-lost error once the request is started? The Server is emulating a HTTP push / long polling -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling and will not end by default.
If there is no new message after 10minutes, the while loop should be exited.

```
import requests
from time import time


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #: Set a default content-length
    content_length = 512
    try:
        requests_stream = requests.get('http://agent.mtconnect.org:80/sample?interval=0', stream=True, timeout=2)
        while True:
            start_time = time()
            #: Read three lines to determine the content-length         
            for line in requests_stream.iter_lines(3, decode_unicode=None):
                if line.startswith('Content-length'):
                    content_length = int(''.join(x for x in line if x.isdigit()))
                    #: pause the generator
                    break

            #: Continue the generator and read the exact amount of the body.        
            for xml in requests_stream.iter_content(content_length):
                print "Received XML document with content length of %s in %s seconds" % (len(xml), time() - start_time)
                break

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print('error: ', e)
```

The server push could be tested with curl via command line:

```
curl http://agent.mtconnect.org:80/sample\?interval\=0
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best method, but you can use multiprocessing to run the requests in a separate process.
Something like this should work:

```
import multiprocessing
import requests
import time

class RequestClient(multiprocessing.Process):
    def run(self):
        # Write all your code to process the requests here
        content_length = 512
        try:
            requests_stream = requests.get('http://agent.mtconnect.org:80/sample?interval=0', stream=True, timeout=2)

            start_time = time.time()
            for line in requests_stream.iter_lines(3, decode_unicode=None):
                if line.startswith('Content-length'):
                    content_length = int(''.join(x for x in line if x.isdigit()))
                    break

            for xml in requests_stream.iter_content(content_length):
                print "Received XML document with content length of %s in %s seconds" % (len(xml), time.time() - start_time) 
                break
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print('error: ', e)


While True:
    childProcess = RequestClient()
    childProcess.start()

    # Wait for 10mins
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time <= 600:
        # Check if the process is still active
        if not childProcess.is_alive():
            # Request completed
            break
        time.sleep(5)    # Give the system some breathing time

    # Check if the process is still active after 10mins.
    if childProcess.is_alive():
        # Shutdown the process
        childProcess.terminate()
        raise RuntimeError("Connection Timed-out")
```

Not the perfect code for your problem, but you get the idea.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like that it works. However, I only receive each 5 seconds a XML message. I need to have those as fast as possible ;)

Comment: The 5 second sleep does not actually hang the child process. It just sleeps the main thread. The XML message should be processed as soon as it is returned in the child process. Most probably, the server or the `requests` module is adding that 5 seconds delay.

Comment: If it worked, you may probably go ahead and accept the answer :)

Comment: it worked, yes. But it is not the ideal solution to have more threads and processes. I thought there is a method/function I could use in the loop. :)

Comment: If the `requests_stream.iter_lines` is a blocking call (which it probably is), then there is no other way to do it because the timeout function in the loop will not be called while waiting for the data.